# android duplication of library files

Tags: android

while importing my eclipse project in android studio.Am getting error like this  LogCat.

`Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\sentientit\Documents\Wed Studio\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk

```
Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE.txt

Origin 1: C:\Users\sentientit\Documents\Wed Studio\app\libs\twitter4j.jar

Origin 2: C:\Users\sentientit\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\joda-time\joda-time\2.4\89e9725439adffbbd41c5f5c215c136082b34a7f\joda-time-2.4.jar
```

You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
  }
}
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
>       File 1: C:\Users\sentientit\Documents\Wed Studio\app\libs\twitter4j.jar
>       File 2: C:\Users\sentientit.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\joda-time\joda-time\2.4\89e9725439adffbbd41c5f5c215c136082b34a7f\joda-time-2.4.jar`

I have deleted the duplicate files still getting errors any body of u tell me the proper way to solve it

Thank you in advance

07-24 17:22:14.789  29926-29926/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
```

ComponentInfo{com.sentientit.theiWedplanner/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment

```
        at
```

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)

```
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at
```

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)

```
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)

        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)



 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error
```

inflating class fragment
            at

android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)

```
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)

        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)

        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)

        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)

        at
```

com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at

com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:50)

```
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
        at
```

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)

at

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'

    }
}
```

Comment: I added this and compiled my project the error has been cleared but my project is not opening in my emulator it get stopped with out opening.

Comment: can you see sth. in the catlog?

Comment: no cant see anything in catlog.while compiling it shows the selection of the device and it get stops before opening

Comment: yes i can see some thing in catlog i posted it above make read on it

Comment: check your layout.xml, look like a problem with `NavigationDrawerFragment`

Comment: `class = "com.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"`

Comment: am not having an xml file like NavigationDrawerFragment